# Merging over a single row from one datafame to another in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge over a one column from one dataframe to another issue I ma having is creating duplicated rows this is what I have:

df =

```
mgr_id     mgr_name     emp_names     num_of_reporting     num_of_billing          total
  101        Adam         Paul                  4                    2               6
  101        Adam         Sam                   4                    2               6
  101        Adam         Karl                  4                    2               6
  101        Adam         Doug                  4                    2               6
  101        Adam         Mike                  4                    2               6
  101        Adam         Mel                   4                    2               6 
  102        Mandy        Fran                  2                    0               2
  102        Mandy        Mary                  2                    0               2
```

df2

```
 mgr_id      mgr_name       emp_billing     num_of_billing
  101          Adam             Mike              2                        
  101          Adam             Mel               2
```

What I want is to merge over the the `emp_billing`
when I do merge using:

`df1 = pd.merge(df1,df2[['mgr_id', 'emp_billing','num_of_billing']], on = 'mgr_id', how = 'left')`

I get duplicated rows in the `emp_reporting` column. Something like this:

```
mgr_id   mgr_name   emp_reporting     num_of_reporting    emp_billing   num_of_billing   total
101        Adam          Paul                 4               Mike            2            6
101        Adam          Paul                 4               Mel             2            6
101        Adam          Mike                 4               Mike            2            6
101        Adam          Mike                 4               Mel             2            6
101        Adam          Mel                  4               Mike            2            6
101        Adam          Mel                  4               Mel             2            6
101        Adam          Sam                  4               Mike            2            6
101        Adam          Sam                  4               Mel             2            6
101        Adam          Karl                 4               Mike            2            6
101        Adam          Karl                 4               Mel             2            6
101        Adam          Doug                 4               Mike            2            6
101        Adam          Doug                 4               Mel             2            6
```

Desired Output:

```
  mgr_id   mgr_name   emp_reporting    num_of_reporting  emp_billing   num_of_billing   total 
     101     Adam         Paul             4               Mike             2            6
     101     Adam         Sam              4               Mel              2            6
     101     Adam         Karl             4               NaN              2            6
     101     Adam         Doug             4               NaN              2            6
     102     Mandy        Mary             2               NaN              0            2
     102     Mandy        Fran             2               NaN              0            2
```

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.